# Flutter | How to communicate between two bluetooth connected mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, cross-platform

Is it possible to read and write data between two bluetooth connected devices in flutter?

List of plugins which i have tried are below, and most of them support only lower energy bluetooth devices(earphones, printer etc.) but i need to transfer data from one mobile phone to another.
plugin links :

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nearby_connections/example
- https://pub.dev/packages/quick_blue
- https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_advanced
- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_custom

Comment: This is way beyond the scope of a stack overflow question as it has so many variables to consider. If you make your question way more specific, you might have more luck - SO questions are intended to provide benefit to the overall community rather than a specific individual. There are numerous factors which are going to define how two devices communicate over BLE.

Comment: That being said, there might be things the community can give you advice about. The first might be to decide how things are going to work in your app - basically, the principles of BLE arrange for there being a device which reads & writes "characteristics" of other devices, but contrarily these devices actually act as servers - which makes sense from a battery life perspective. If you have a very low energy device, it is less intensive to just wait for a request to come in. But this means that if you're using BLE for an app, you need to figure out how that could work in the context of your app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

flutter_blue_plus plugin is popular for all kinds of Bluetooth devices you can give it a try.

For plugin reference:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus